# MySQL - Dataset based on field list, if field not there enter dummy row for that field

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok,

So I've tried to find a similar question on here about this.  Not seeing one that relates exactly.

I have a table that has sales data by state.  The data is organised like this;

SELECT * FROM SALES_BY_STATE;

```
PRODUCTGROUP    SALES   STATE   MONTH   YEAR
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    A       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    B       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    F       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    G       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    H       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    I       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    J       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    K       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    A       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    B       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    C       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    D       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    E       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    F       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    G       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    H       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    I       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    J       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    K       JAN     2016
```

I have 11 states (A - K).  I want to create a statement that shows the states regardless of whether there is a related row for that state.  As you can see in the above data, PRODUCT2 has record for state A - K.  However, PRODUCTGROUP1 is missing some.

I want to extract the data and display it as follows;

```
PRODUCTGROUP    SALES   STATE   MONTH   YEAR
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    A       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    B       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   0       C       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   0       D       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   0       E       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    F       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    G       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    H       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    I       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    J       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP1   1000    K       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    A       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    B       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    C       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    D       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    E       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    F       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    G       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    H       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    I       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    J       JAN     2016
PRODUCTGROUP2   1000    K       JAN     2016
```

Does that make sense?  I basically want to show the state in the result regardless of whether there is a related line in the dataset.

Not sure how I would go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very non-trivial problem.  I think you would need to create some sort of "calendar" table containing all the states, and then you'd need some dynamic SQL to generate the missing records.  I don't think that non dynamic SQL could do it, because the relation between product groups and states simply does not exist in many cases of your data set.

Comment: Thanks Tim, maybe I need to consider writing a program to put the missing records into the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an overall list using Cartesian product. Note that we are building this from the existing data, so if you decide all of a sudden that you have a STATE "L" then there must be at least one row in the SALES_BY_STATE table with that STATE. Same goes for time period.

Using some temporary tables will prevent the cartesian product from blowing up if you have a large table.

```
create temporary table if not exists pg AS select distinct PRODUCTGROUP from SALES_BY_STATE;
create temporary table if not exists st AS select distinct STATE from SALES_BY_STATE;
create temporary table if not exists mo AS select distinct MONTH from SALES_BY_STATE;
create temporary table if not exists yr AS select distinct YEAR from SALES_BY_STATE;

select list.PRODUCTGROUP, list.STATE, list.MONTH,
    list.YEAR, IFNULL(s.SALES, 0) 

FROM
    (select distinct PRODUCTGROUP, STATE, MONTH, YEAR 
    FROM pg, st, mo, yr  ) as list

LEFT JOIN
    SALES_BY_STATE as s
ON
    list.PRODUCTGROUP = s.PRODUCTGROUP and list.STATE = s.STATE
   and list.MONTH = s.MONTH AND list.YEAR = s.YEAR
ORDER BY
    list.PRODUCTGROUP, list.STATE, list.MONTH, list.YEAR
```

Comment: I was just about to comment and I read your edit.. it is a good solution, but not a very efficient one give the size of the table I am working with.  Thanks a heap for the suggestion though.

Comment: I just updated my solution, this should run a lot faster.

Comment: Mate, brilliant solution! Thanks for that, it worked perfectly!  I was just building some reporting tables to try and work a solution with that.  Excellent mate.  I owe you beers too